# How do I make Evil's C-o work with Org's C-c C-o?

Tags: org-mode, evil

Org mode's `org-open-at-point` (<kbd>C-c C-o</kbd>) works great for internal links, e.g.

```
Stuff to buy:
- <<food>> food:
  - tomato
  - potato
  - banana
- <<drinks>> drinks:
  - juice
  - tea
  - coffee

Maybe look for some more variation for [[food]]?
```

However, when I use `org-open-at-point` in `[[food]]`, Evil mode's `evil-jump-backward` (<kbd>C-o</kbd>) does not bring me back to my original position. Org mode itself tells me in the echo area to use <kbd>C-c &</kbd> (`org-mark-ring-goto`) instead, but I would like to use `evil-jump-backward` to remember only a single keybinding.

Is it possible to use Evil's <kbd>C-o</kbd> also movements via `org-open-at-point`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides @Zeta‘s answer. a less intrusive way could be:

```
(evil-set-command-property 'org-open-at-point :jump t)
```

for how it works, just inspect `evil--jump-hook` which is in `pre-command-hook`.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. `evil-jump-backward` knows where to jump to via `evil-set-jump`. All we need to do is to call `evil-set-jump` before we jump in `org-open-at-point`. We need to [advice](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html) the function for that:

```lisp
(advice-add 'org-open-at-point :before 'evil-set-jump)
```

This makes sure that before `org-open-at-point` gets called, `evil-set-jump` gets called first, therefore saving the location. <kbd>C-o</kbd> will then work as intended.